# Prevent another event from firing before a previous one is complete in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

http://jsfiddle.net/jmPCt/18/

I'm quite new to JS and jQuery. I've written all the code by hand in the link above. It works and does what I want it to save for but one thing. If you click rapidly on the 'next' link, you'll see either a flash of the next container to display or, if you click rapidly enough, the code will display two containers but I only want one to show only at a time. Is there some way of handling this in jQuery? I've tried using stops as discussed here: [How to prevent jquery hover event from firing when not complete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6512644/how-to-prevent-jquery-hover-event-from-firing-when-not-complete) but this does not solve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `.stop()`. It's implementation changes with the desired behavior but the documentation should clear that up for you: http://api.jquery.com/stop

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jmPCt/19/

Because of how `.stop()` works, when you use it with `.fadeIn()` or `.fadeOut()` you can chop-up your animations to the point where they no longer work. The best fix I've found is to always animate to absolute values with `.fadeTo()`: http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo

Here is the code I added to your JSFiddle, this overwrites the default `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut()` jQuery functions with ones that use `.fadeTo()` and `.stop()`:

```
$.fn.fadeOut = function (duration, callback) {
    $(this).stop().fadeTo(duration, 0, function () {
        $(this).css('display', 'none');
        if (typeof callback == 'function') {
            callback();
        }
    });
};
$.fn.fadeIn = function (duration, callback) {
    $(this).css('display', 'block').stop().fadeTo(duration, 1, function () {
        if (typeof callback == 'function') {
            callback();
        }
    });
};
```

## Update

If you set the `position` property for the "slide" elements then they can animate on top of each other which will remove the jumpiness that your code exhibits:

HTML --

```
<div id="controls">
    <div id="countah"></div>
    <a href="#" id=prev>prev</a> | 
    <a href="#" id=next>next</a>
</div>
```

CSS --

```
.js .staceyPort {
    display: none;
    position : absolute;
    top      : 0;
    left     : 0;
}

#controls{ 
    position   : fixed;
    bottom     : 0;
    left       : 0;
    z-index    : 1000;
    background : gold;
}​
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jmPCt/21/

Comment: yes, i've tried the .stop() method: http://jsfiddle.net/jmPCt/20/ but perhaps I am not using the right params on it?? .stop( [clearQueue] [, jumpToEnd] ) so .stop(true, true), yes?

Comment: @jonny.milano See the **update** to my answer. Try absolutely positioning the slides so they can animate on top of each other without messing with the rest of the page: http://jsfiddle.net/jmPCt/21/

Comment: wow, that is 'absolutely' ;) amazing! thanks so much. I can see why you have 26.2k reputation! works much better now and your trick to use .fadeTo() is great! interestingly, in chrome if you click really fast the code can still exhibit this behavior (sort of): http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7573777/z_working-folder/Untitled.jpg anyways, this is MUCH better. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. In a general sense, you should always set the `position` of any element you are going to animate to `absolute`. This allows the element to be animated without needing to redraw the entire page (which is what happens when you animate `position : relative` elements. If you set `position : absolute` on an element and animate it, the browser will only have to redraw the region of the element.